# Read large amount of records (Batch READ) DB2

Tags: sql, performance, db2, rdbms

Hi I need to read sequentially without too much filtering a lot of data from a DB2 table. In order to paralelize the READs I am first reading all the elements from an index with good cardinality (not too much duplications) then I partition them in lists of 100 and then I use

```
SELECT from TABLE where mycolumn in ('value1','value2'....'value100') with UR
```

After turning on the tracing some of the SQLs it apears that a result set of 5000 records is served for :

```
User CPU: 0.032192 seconds
System CPU: 0.003841 seconds
```

The DB2 is on SSD drive. Why does it take 32ms user time ?

On the Java side I have configured the JDBC driver to use `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`

One more detail, I need to populate an in-memory structure with data fast. For this purpose I need to be capable of reading fast the data from the database.

Can it be that the DB2 buffers are set too low ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Tuning the database is about configuration and access-plans. That is a matter of configuration , not programming. Bufferpool size, prefetch size for the tablespace, number of prefetchers, whether the bufferpool(s) are seeded, available RAM for Db2 , rqrioblk, all play a part.  All configuration, not programming.  It is unclear why you tagged Oracle on your question.

Comment: @mao what would play biggest role when we talk about selecting a lot of records ? Buffer + prefetch +  RAM ?

Comment: @mao i tagged it also with oracle because I think that the general concepts should be the same. The terms you enumerated are the same in oracle. It is a very generic question. Fast way to read millions of rows in one go.

Comment: Perhaps a 'generic' question, but each rdbms product is profoundly different from the others in it's internal architecture and implementation.  Something that is highly configurable in one may not even exist as a concept in another.  And don't forget that the time may be outside of the database .. like the amount of time needed to move the data across the network between the db and the client.

Comment: If you are not using parameter markers, I would assume your CPU is being used in compiling your query each time

Comment: @PaulVernon I am using parameter markers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
Select *
from TABLE t
where mod(mycolumn, N)=x
```

N - number of parallel streams
x - [0, N-1] - stream number

If you don’t have `mycolumn` with cardinality high enough, try `rid(t)` expression instead of `mycolumn`.

[rid](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050679.html) function reference.

Comment: This does not work for me. My main cycle is oriented around  the mycolumn.